# How to NOT Have Tables/DataFiles Appear in SAS Enterprise Guide Window

Tags: sas

What option may I select in SAS Enterprise Guide so that generated tables or datasets do not appear in the Project Workspace? I have a lot of them and it is getting very messy.

Please note that I already defined my own library to place data files - and there are plenty of them.

I can right-click on my Workspace, then click on Project/Properties and I set Output Data Sets to zero, and that sort of solves the program. However, numerous messages, or Reports, appear within my Window specifying that the output was not written. I think it was still written to my user-defined libraries though - I HOPE I am correct there.

Any help and/or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok.  Read the SAS Blog entry ["SAS Enterprise Guide: Suppress Output Data tab when programming"](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sastraining/2015/06/17/sas-enterprise-guide-suppress-output-data-tab-when-programming/), By Cindy Cragin on SAS Learning Post June 17, 2015.

> There is an easy way to suppress the Output Data tab in the data grid window from opening up in your Enterprise Guide session after submitting a SAS program.
>   …
>   Here is your answer. Select Tools -> Options -> Results -> Results General and set the value of 'Maximum number of output data sets to add to the project' to 0.

This will also prevent the output data sets from being listed in the process flow diagram.

Suppose you had a program node such as:

```
libname t 'c:\temp';

data t._1 t._2 t._3 t._4 t._5;
  set sashelp.class;
  select (mod(_n_,5));
    when (0) output t._1;
    when (1) output t._2;
    when (2) output t._3;
    when (3) output t._4;
    when (4) output t._5;
    otherwise;
  end;
run;
```

The Enterprise Guide 8.1 UI would show

[image]

with Log panel indicating the output was indeed created.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. What did work was to click on Process Flow / Properties / Project Properties - then set the Maximum number of output data sets to add to the project - set it to zero. But I still receive many windows specifying Data Set Limit Reached. Any way to rid of that as well?

Comment: I don't think there is an option that filters or prevents EG from doing it's baseline process flow representation.  You might consider running the project in batch mode and not have to look at anything.  Try a read of https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/05/03/using-sas-enterprise-guide-to-run-programs-in-batch/   Basically EG can creates a Windows script to run the project.

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to do the same? _In a sasautos macro, I create a dataset I want to hide for the users._